# Co-ordinate Geometry Equation of a circle

Tags: geometry

Find the equation of the circle having the lines x+1=0 and x-3=0 as tangents and with its center lying on the line y=3

I don't know much maths so if you could tell me also how to get the co-ordinates of the three lines it wold be very helpful

Comment: You really need help because you are running out of time or you really need help because you don't understand the problem?

Comment: Pleading for fast help does not go over as well as providing (even just a little bit) about what you've tried so far. If you do the latter thing, you usually will get quick help right away.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Draw a picture of these three lines
2. Notice that the tangents are parallel, so they are going to touch the circle at diametrically opposite points.
3. Locate where the center is going to be on your picture. This should help you deduce both the center and the radius. Using those data, write the equation of this particular circle.